# How to output concurrent users in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to produce a query that outputs the number of concurrent users between certain times of the day. I will be using a variable to allow me to select a particular day.

The table has a login_time field which is datetime, and a logout_time field which is also datetime. Basically, I want to be able to output to an hour column if the user is logged in at any point during that hour.

A case statement wouldn't be scalable, so if I wanted to reduce to fifteen minute segments rather than an hour, I would effectively need 48 case statements.

Is there a better way to handle a query such as this to output concurrent user logins? Happy for a solution to be delivered anywhere in the MSBI stack.

Comment: please explain in terms of examples rather in terms of words,you can look here for more ways to improve question ..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: so you want to output how many users logged on during a window, which can be dynamic, i.e. 15 mins, or 30 mins, or an hour etc. and you want this in columns rather than rows? I'd say rows may make more sense, then you have a  column for time and a column for count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got set times that you're doing the query for (say the shortest is 15 minutes) then you could create a date table to link to rather than calculate it on the fly.

Say we had this sample data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (loginID int, login_time datetime, logout_time datetime)
INSERT INTO #TestData (loginID, login_time, logout_time)
VALUES
('1','2016-06-08 09:10:00','2016-06-08 10:10:00')
,('2','2016-06-08 08:55:00','2016-06-08 10:55:00')
,('3','2016-06-08 09:29:00','2016-06-08 10:29:00')
,('4','2016-06-08 09:40:00','2016-06-08 10:40:00')
,('5','2016-06-08 09:08:00','2016-06-08 10:08:00')
,('6','2016-06-08 09:04:00','2016-06-08 10:04:00')
,('7','2016-06-08 09:12:00','2016-06-08 10:12:00')
,('8','2016-06-08 09:40:00','2016-06-08 10:40:00')
,('9','2016-06-08 09:21:00','2016-06-08 10:21:00')
```

You could create a date table like this (this is a very simplified version for this example);

```
CREATE TABLE #DateTimeTable (ReferenceDate datetime, RefHour datetime)
INSERT INTO #DateTimeTable
VALUES
('2016-06-08 08:45:00','2016-06-08 08:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 09:00:00','2016-06-08 09:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 09:15:00','2016-06-08 09:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 09:30:00','2016-06-08 09:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 09:45:00','2016-06-08 09:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 10:00:00','2016-06-08 10:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 10:15:00','2016-06-08 10:00:00')
,('2016-06-08 10:30:00','2016-06-08 10:00:00')
```

Then if you wanted the results for users by every 15 minutes you could use this query;

```
SELECT 
dtt.ReferenceDate
,COUNT(td.loginID) Users
FROM #TestData td
CROSS JOIN #DateTimeTable dtt
WHERE td.login_time <= dtt.ReferenceDate
    AND td.logout_time > dtt.ReferenceDate
GROUP BY dtt.ReferenceDate
```

Which gives this result;

```
ReferenceDate                Users
2016-06-08 09:00:00.000      1
2016-06-08 09:15:00.000      5
2016-06-08 09:30:00.000      7
2016-06-08 09:45:00.000      9
2016-06-08 10:00:00.000      9
2016-06-08 10:15:00.000      5
2016-06-08 10:30:00.000      3
```

If you wanted it by hour then you could use this one;

```
SELECT 
dtt.RefHour
,COUNT(td.loginID) Users
FROM #TestData td
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RefHour FROM #DateTimeTable) dtt
WHERE td.login_time <= dtt.RefHour
    AND td.logout_time > dtt.RefHour
GROUP BY dtt.RefHour
```

To give this result;

```
RefHour                   Users
2016-06-08 09:00:00.000   1
2016-06-08 10:00:00.000   9
```

The advantage of the table is that once it's created you can use the results in all number of queries within your database in order to increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

here's a way of getting timeslots of a defined length during the day, you can then JOIN or CROSS APPLY or otherwise use the TIMESLOTS CTE in queries to summarize data within those slots - timeslot length would be 60 in your case

```
DECLARE @SLOTMINS AS INTEGER;

SET @SLOTMINS = 15;

;with TIMESLOTS AS
    (SELECT CAST('00:00' as datetime) as start, 0 as mins
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT dateadd(n, @SLOTMINS, TIMESLOTS.start), mins + @SLOTMINS from TIMESLOTS WHERE  mins + @SLOTMINS < 1440
    )
    select * from TIMESLOTS
```